# How to show an element only on a specific route?

Tags: angular

I have a Navbar with some basic login and signup routing, but the thing is, on the home page ('/') i have an about us section which i don't want to show when i'm in the login('/login') or the signup('/signup') page. So how can i show that section only on the route('/')?

Comment: see updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.ts` file

```
export class Page {
  __URL:string = ""
  constructor(router: Router) {
   console.log(router.url); // This will print the current url
   this.__URL = this.router.url;
  }
}
```

And in you `.html` file, You can make use of `*ngIf`

```
<div *ngIf="__URL === '/'">
 // Render whatever you want
</div>
```

## #Edit

Try `Location` instead of `Router`

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private location: Location) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.location.path());
  }

}
```

Feel free to see [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/Location)

In case it does not work , Try the following

```
 this.router.events
  .pipe(
    filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
  )
  .subscribe( (navEnd:NavigationEnd) => {
    console.log(navEnd.urlAfterRedirects);
  });
```

Comment: this didn't work for me, and in the console it would log the route '/' no matter which route i'm on.

Comment: I really don't know what's wrong here in both solutions u provided, the console.log works perfectly but the about us section is either shown on all routes or hidden on all routes

Comment: Manipulate it with ``*ngIf``

Answer (score 3):

You can use the router [`events`](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events) combined with the resolved `urlAfterRedirects` inside the events object:

```
export class NavComponent {
  readonly showAbout$ = this.router.events.pipe(
    filter((event) => event instanceOf NavigationEnd)
    map((event) => this.canShowAbout(event.urlAfterRedirects)),
    startWith(this.canShowAbout(this.router.url))
  )

  constructor(readonly router: Router) {}

  canShowAbout(url: string): boolean {
    return ['/login', '/signup'].every((path) => !url.startsWith(path)
  }
}
```

and in your component use the `async` pipe:

```
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/home">Home</a>
  <a *ngIf="showAbout$ | async" routerLink="/about">
    About
  </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: I noticed in your code that youd don't subscribe to ``events`` , Am i wrong ?

Comment: @Abdulrahman that is true, this is handled with the angular `async` pipe. I prefer this way, because you don't have to worry about hanging subscriptions, or change detection not working in `OnPush`

Comment: Thank you , I did not notice it